# Unable to run Headless Chrome Browser on Linux Machine using Selenium Webdriver java

Tags: java, linux, google-chrome, selenium

Used Selenium Webdriver(**V2.29**), selenium-api version(**3.4.0**), Chrome 
Version (**62.0.3202.94**) **64 bit** and tried to run chrome browser in linux machine with the below code.

```
    WebDriver driver;
    String chromeBinaryPath = "/data/Package/CHROME_NEW";
    String driverPath = "/data/Package/Selenium/WebDrivers/ChromeDrivers/chromedriver_linux32/chromedriver";

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging","true");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile","/data/Package/log/chromedriver.log");


    ChromeOptions optionsLinux64 = new ChromeOptions();

    optionsLinux64.setBinary(chromeBinaryPath);
    optionsLinux64.addArguments("--headless");
    optionsLinux64.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    optionsLinux64.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    optionsLinux64.addArguments("--headless");

    driver = new ChromeDriver(optionsLinux64);
```

When tried to create a chrome session, getting below exception:

> unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 60.10 seconds Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host: 'el4014.bc', ip: '10.120.94.70', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_151' Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Installed Chrome at **/data/Package/CHROME_NEW** folder using rpm file.

Message in chromedriver.log:

> [0.204][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12111/json/version
>   LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:
>   /data/Package/CHROME_NEW/
>   [0.379][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed

Can anyone help me in resolving with the above issue.

Answer (score 1):

This should be work:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setHeadless(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding window size
    optionsLinux64.addArguments("window-size=1024x780");

Comment: You can emphasize which part of your answer is code by surrounding it with backticks (``).